Problem when trying to load the config of hydra
I am running the python script in google collab. When I do this I am getting an error with the config but I am unsure on how to fix this
The code snippet:
import hydra
from pathlib import Path  # Import Path for file path handling
import sys  # Import the sys module

@hydra.main(config_path="cfgs", config_name="config.yaml")
def main(cfg):
   print(cfg) # Print the parsed configuration
   from train import Workspace as W
   root_dir = Path.cwd()

   workspace = W(cfg)

   snapshot = root_dir / 'snapshot.pt'

   if snapshot.exists():
      print(f'resuming: {snapshot}')
      workspace.load_snapshot()

   workspace.train()



if __name__ == '__main__':
     main() 

The output I get is this:
usage: colab_kernel_launcher.py [--help] [--hydra-help] [-- 
version] [--cfg {job,hydra,all}]
                               [--resolve] [--package PACKAGE] [-- 
run] [--multirun]
                            [--shell-completion] [--config-path 
CONFIG_PATH]
                            [--config-name CONFIG_NAME] [--config- 
dir CONFIG_DIR]
                            [--info 
[{all,config,defaults,defaults-tree,plugins,searchpath}]]
                            [overrides ...]
colab_kernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
    SystemExit: 2


How do you launch your script? Somehow colab_kernel_launcher.py -f is executed which causes hydra to complain. To check you can also print(sys.argv) either before main() or @hydra.main.

To me there seems like there are a bunch of errors.
First try import pathlib from Path.
Then try these to see where the actual error is:
try:
if snapshot.exists():
    print(f"resuming: {snapshot}")
    workspace.load_snapshot()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error loading snapshot: {e}")

try:
    workspace.train()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during training: {e}")

Hope it helps
